# Diseases that require long-term hospital admission

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, diseases

Is there an illness wherein

1) it can be diagnosed in teens(16-18 preferably) and could eventually lead to death.

2) it requires long-term admission to the hospital because the condition may worsen if the person leaves the hospital.

3) it does not affect brain activity (no memory loss and not mental health-related).

4) there are no visible and obvious symptoms that point to the sickness.

5) it is not cancer.

Thank you for the responses!!

Comment: what kind of long-term do you have in mind - 6-8 weeks, 6-8 months, 6-8 years or lifetime?

Comment: can be 6-8 yrs or lifetime

Comment: [Polio - in its paralytic evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polio) - doesn't quite keep you in a hospital, but may keep you in a wheel chair for your entire life.

Comment: kidney damage that don't qualify to transplant.

Comment: Duchenne muscular dystrophy perhaps

Comment: How is this actually about worldbuilding? And not, say, medicine?

Comment: I tend to agree with @elemtilas; while this is technically about worldbuilding, you would be better served to ask it on MedicalSciences.SE

Comment: Framing challenge: does it have to be 6-8 years? Alternatively, can the patient be in a coma for this period? Something like meningitis could cause a coma, which the patient doesn't wake from for several years. Otherwise, 6-8 years will be a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Doctors try quite hard to get patients out of hospital, because keeping them there is very expensive. What historical period is this for?

[Severe combined immunodeficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_combined_immunodeficiency), aka "Baby in a bubble" required this kind of treatment in the 1950s and 1960s, but since then  can be treated with bone marrow transplants. It's also usually diagnosed in early childhood, and developing it as a teenager would be very unusual.

Comment: its modern-day period

Comment: @chrlsmm: Added dates, but this probably won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Multi drug resistant TB in its asymptomatic form fits everything except the length of stay but as I'll discuss later the length of stay you would like is extremely long for a hospital stay.

TB or Consumption, as it was known, is the classic long hospital stay disease, often requiring several months of isolation and treatment. It was a rather sinister disease because it would sit benignly in 90% of cases. Even worse, while some active would have symptoms such as coughing or fevers, others could only be detected by lung x-rays showing the damage the disease was doing.

TB was eventually brought under control by drugs that dropped the treatment time down from months to a couple of weeks. That is until the 1980s when Multi drug resistant TB (MDR-TB) started appearing. Because it is resistant to the drugs that brought TB under control originally we are back to recommending long term isolation (for example page 214 of [this](https://www.health.govt.nz/publication/guidelines-tuberculosis-control-new-zealand-2019) guideline from the New Zealand Ministry of Health).

So to go over the criteria:

- It can be contracted at any age but you are more likely to get it in late adolescence (15+) so your 16-18 preference is right about when people start having a higher risk of contraction.
- This is a lung disease, so normally no brain effects (though there can be in rare cases).
- Common signs are chest pains and prolonged coughs but about a quarter of people are asymptomatic.
- Obviously it is not cancer.
- But the sticking point is TB would require a hospital stay of months up to about a year where as you would like 6-8+ years. I would like to challenge this.

6-8 years is incredibly long for a modern hospital stay. For example this US National Library of Medicine article [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5898738/) shows that for a South Koran hospital in 2013 the average stay is 7 days and their longest recorded was 243 days. Even for long term conditions, if someone is not contagious or only mildly contagious, and they do not require immediate care, hospitals prefer to discharge, both to free up beds and to allow patients to return home where they will most likely be more comfortable.

So I would say you've got two options, scale down how long you want the patient to be in hospital or be prepared to use a bit of handwavium and say that the doctors can prevent the progression of the disease but cannot cure it and cannot prevent it form being contagious, requiring long term isolation in hospital for several years.